# Error message when creating query against Resource Manager, in Azure Monitor Workbook

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm trying to add a query into a Workbook in Azure Monitor that queries for the month-to-date usage costs for my Azure subscription.

When I construct the query and run it, I receive the following error message:

> BadRequest: Invalid query definition, Dataset is invalid or not supplied.

However, the documentation for this REST API call specifically indicates that the `datasets` property of the body is not required.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage

Screenshot of docs:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of what my query looks like in the Workbook:

[image]

**Question**: How do I properly construct the body for this request, when the documentation doesn't properly explain it?

Comment: is it ok f you leave the dataset field out of the request then?  having it *there* but an empty string might be invalid?  (can you do just `{ timeframe ... type... }` ?

Comment: and, if the docs are wrong, i'd suggest using the thumbs down in the docs themselves and submitting feedback that they're wrong so they can be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this [api-doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage#examples) provides many examples, you can click any of the example for the request body details.

Take [BillingAccountQuery-Modern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage#billingaccountquery-modern) for example, the request body is as below(you can modify it as per your need):

```
{
  "type": "Usage",
  "timeframe": "MonthToDate",
  "dataset": {
    "granularity": "Daily",
    "filter": {
      "and": [
        {
          "or": [
            {
              "dimension": {
                "name": "ResourceLocation",
                "operator": "In",
                "values": [
                  "East US",
                  "West Europe"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "tag": {
                "name": "Environment",
                "operator": "In",
                "values": [
                  "UAT",
                  "Prod"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dimension": {
            "name": "ResourceGroup",
            "operator": "In",
            "values": [
              "API"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But the documentation clearly shows that the `dataset` parameter is not required. Did you see the screenshot in my post?

Comment: @TrevorSullivan, yes, I saw that. Even though it says that the `dataset` is not required, but actually you need at least specify the `dataset` with `granularity`, like this: `{ "dataset": {"granularity": "Daily"}, "type": "ActualCost","timeframe": "BillingMonthToDate"}`. Otherwise, it will throw an error.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan, hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Comment: (actually, randomly this one showed up at the TOP of stackoverflow for me so i thought it was new.  If i look at the api docs NOW, the dataset parameter *is* shown as required)